# Converting from hardcode to reading from plist

Tags: swift, xcode

Very new to xcode, I was looking up on how to build a quiz app and I found a youtube video to refer from but only problem is he hardcoded the questions and the answers. I want to ask how can i change this part of the QuestionBank class to read from a plist or json file? The video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXbG9RS3C5A

The QuestionBank class

```
class QuestionBank{
    var list = [Question]()

    init() {
        list.append(Question(image: "flag1", questionText: "This British overseas territory is a popular tax haven.", choiceA: "A. Haiti", choiceB: "B. Suriname", choiceC: "C. Puerto Rico", choiceD: "D. Anguilla", answer: 4))

        list.append(Question(image: "flag2", questionText: "The highest point on this island, Mount Obama was renamed in 2009 in honor of the president.", choiceA: "A. Dominica", choiceB: "B. Bahamas", choiceC: "C. Antigua and Barbuda", choiceD: "British Virgin Islands", answer: 3))

        list.append(Question(image: "flag3", questionText: "This country produces its water from a desalination plant and the electricity on the island is a by-product of the desalination process.", choiceA: "A. Cuba", choiceB: "B. Aruba", choiceC: "C. Gaudeloupe", choiceD: "D. Cayman Islands", answer: 2))

        list.append(Question(image: "flag4", questionText: "This country has a magnificent underwater cave system.", choiceA: "A. The Bahamas", choiceB: "B. Venezuela", choiceC: "C. Matinique", choiceD: "D. Dominican Republic", answer: 1))

        list.append(Question(image: "flag5" , questionText: "This is the island of Cou-Cou and Flying Fish. The popular R&B singer Rihanna is from here.", choiceA: "A. Trinidad and Tobago" , choiceB: "B. Saint Kitts and Nevis" , choiceC: "C. Grenada" , choiceD: "D. Barbados", answer: 4))

        list.append(Question(image: "flag15" , questionText: "Rum is the national drink of this country. The fastest man in the world Usain Bolt is from here.", choiceA: "A. Jamaica" , choiceB: "B. Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" , choiceC: "C. St. Lucia" , choiceD: "D. Guyana", answer: 1))
    }
}
```

The Question class:

```
class Question {
    let questionImage: String
    let question: String
    let optionA: String
    let optionB: String
    let optionC: String
    let optionD: String
    let correctAnswer: Int

    init(image: String, questionText: String, choiceA: String, choiceB: String, choiceC: String, choiceD: String, answer: Int){
        questionImage = image
        question = questionText
        optionA = choiceA
        optionB = choiceB
        optionC = choiceC
        optionD = choiceD
        correctAnswer = answer
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at some of the many good tutorials that are around concerning JSON decoding with Swift and the Codable protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your property list file using the built-in property list editor in Xcode. It will look like this (just showing the first couple of questions):

[image]

Now drag the property list file into your app bundle and be sure to make it part of the app target.

Now it is trivial to read in the property list file when the app launches. For example:

```
struct QuestionBank : Codable {
    let list : [Question]
}
struct Question : Codable {
    let image: String
    let questionText: String
    let choiceA: String
    let choiceB: String
    let choiceC: String
    let choiceD: String
    let answer: Int
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var questionBank : QuestionBank?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "questions", withExtension: "plist")
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        self.questionBank = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(QuestionBank.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

(Notice that there needs to be a match between the names of your struct properties and the names of the keys in the plist file, and I've adjusted the names for that purpose. Another solution would be to use the CodingKeys to remap the names but there seems little purpose in doing that here, as yo are in control of the names.)

Answer (score 0):

First you can transform your `class` into a `struct` and use the protocol `Codable` (combination of two protocol, `Encodable` and `Decodable`), this allows you to decode a JSON into an object or an array of objects.

`CodingKeys` allows you to match keys that are not in the format or name that you want.

```swift
struct Question: Codable {

    // Optional
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case questionImage = "q_image" // Example
        case age, single
    }

    let questionImage: String
    let question: String
    let optionA: String
    let optionB: String
    let optionC: String
    let optionD: String
    let correctAnswer: Int
}
```

Now you should parse the data, I'm considering your plist has just an array of questions corresponding to the object declared above, if not create different objects and match the keys.

```swift
guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourPlistName", ofType: "plist"),
    let plistURL = URL(string: plistPath),
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: plistURL) else {
        fatalError("Do something!")
}

let questions = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data)
```

Hope this is useful enough to anyone.